# Is there any way to know how much memory an ElementTree DOM consumes?

Tags: python, xml, dom, memory, elementtree

Suppose you do the following:

```
dom = ElementTree()
dom.parse(some_file_path)
```

I'd like to log the rough amount of memory that this dom is now using in my process.  I don't need something precise, something rough would do.

I don't think I can derive it from the size of the source XML file.  I have a 500 kilobyte file that seems to add about 5MB to the memory usage of my python process after it's loaded as in the example above.

I looked over the ElementTree API and didn't see any API to provide this information.  Anyone know of a way to know how much memory the ElementTree instance is using after parsing/loading an XML file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially you want to find memory consumption of a particular python object. That's what it is. Here its an `ElementTree` object but it can be anything.

To cut the chase short as far as I know **There's no easy way to find out the memory size of a python object**. One of the problems you may find is that Python objects - like lists and dicts - may have references to other python objects (in this case, what would your size be? The size containing the size of each object or not?). There are some pointers overhead and internal structures related to object types and garbage collection. Finally, some python objects have non-obvious behaviors. For instance, lists reserve space for more objects than they have, most of the time; dicts are even more complicated since they can operate in different ways (they have a different implementation for small number of keys and sometimes they over allocate entries).

- There is a [big chunk of code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/544288/) out there to try to best approximate the size of a python object in memory. There's also some [simpler approximations](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-January/472683.html). But they will always be approximations.
- You may also want to check some [old description about PyObject](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-March/135223.html) (the internal C struct that represents virtually all python objects).
- also, PySizer, "a memory profiler for Python," found at http://pysizer.8325.org/.  However the page seems to indicate that the project hasn't been updated for a while, and refers to...
- You could give Heapy a try, "support[ing] debugging and optimization regarding memory related issues in Python programs," found at http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy.
- objgraph looks interesting: http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/

Comment: I think solving this more general problem is more difficult than solving the specific problem OP asked for.  You can get an approximation by accumulating the size of each node's attributes plus its contents (recursively) and adding the size of contents for CData and text nodes.

Comment: Those are a lot of useful links, I'll take a look at them - thanks!  You're definitely right that when a number of objects reference each other, the idea measuring the size of any one of them becomes less meaningful.  I guess I hoped that in this case the ElementTree instance doesn't reference anything in my code.  However to your point, two different ElementTree objects may share non-obvious objects at lower layers, etc.